# update value of object property inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
(
    [title] => test
    [type] => location
    [status] => 1
    [field_locationmap] => stdClass Object
        (
            [und] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [geom] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [lon] => 151.19555790000004
                                )

                        )

                )
```

I would like to ask how I can change the value of the 'lon' value, since it is an object inside an array?

Answer (score 0):

If the initial variable is an array that will do:

```
$zero = 0;
$lon = $array['field_locationmap']->und->$zero->geom->lon;
```

else if the initial variable is an stdClass object:

```
$zero = 0;
$lon = $object->field_locationmap->und->$zero->geom->lon;
```

So finally if you want to change this value you should just do:

```
$array['field_locationmap']->und->$zero->geom->lon = 'new value here';
```